# How to add google play store button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add google play store button in my website. I am using reactjs and material-ui. I tried searching it online but didn;t find any help. I am a beginner in reactjs can anyone help me please?

Comment: just put any image with href with your google play web link.

Comment: thank you will do that

Comment: maybe there is better way than just a link. for example if you are on mobile, when you click on a link it open applestore or google play in the web browser, but you are not logged in, i should open the appleStore/googlePlay directly on the phone to download it easly

Answer (score 0):

we can add Google Play Store button using "react-mobile-app-button" react component. We can add App Store, Google Play, and AppGallery download buttons using this component. This is a sample code for it.

```
    import { GooglePlayButton } from "react-mobile-app-button";
    
    export const MyComponent = () => {
      const APKUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host";
    
      return (
        <div>
          <GooglePlayButton
            url={APKUrl}
            theme={"light"}
            className={"custom-style"}
          />
        </div>
      );
   };
```